# Optimizing SQL Server Query with #temp Table and group by Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, temp-tables

I have below query it is working as expected but taking long time to execute.

To obtain result i have fetched the records in temp table and then applied groupby to obtain final result

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp From (

  select A.*,B.* 
  from (
    select e.Id,e.code,e.Fname,
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.BUDHOL) as [BUDHOL],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.COMPANY) as [COMPANY],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.BENEFICIARY) as [BENEFICIARY],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.SPARE2) as [SPARE2],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.SPARE1) as [SPARE1],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.EXPORG) as [EXPORG],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.EXPTYPE) as [EXPTYPE],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.OBJECTIVE) as [OBJECTIVE],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.TASKNO) as [TASKNO],
      (select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.PROJECTNO) as [PROJECTNO]
    from dbo.EmployeeDetail e  
    left join (
      select * 
      from (
        select CustomeFieldName,FieldValue,CompanyId,EmployeeId   
        from  dbo.CustomeFieldDetail   
        where CustomeFieldName in ('BENEFICIARY','BUDHOL','COMPANY', 'EXPORG','EXPTYPE','OBJECTIVE','PROJECTNO','SPARE2','SPARE1','TASKNO','COMPANY') and CompanyId = 1 
      )as src  
      pivot (max(FieldValue) for CustomeFieldName in ([BENEFICIARY],[BUDHOL],[EXPORG],[EXPTYPE],[OBJECTIVE],[PROJECTNO],[SPARE2],[SPARE1],[TASKNO],[COMPANY])
            ) as src2
    ) c on e.Id = c.EmployeeId   and e.CompanyId = c.CompanyId and e.DateOfJoining <= convert(datetime,'30/03/2016',103) and e.CompanyId = 1       
    where e.Companyid=1 --order by e.Code
  ) A
  Full Outer join (
    select
      T.EmployeeId,
      X.[FieldName],
      X.[Value]
    from dbo.EmpTransaction T
    cross apply (
      SELECT         
        T.c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') AS [FieldName],
        convert(float,T.c.value('(@Value)[1]', 'Varchar(max)')) AS [Value]
      FROM TransactionFieldDetails.nodes('//PayDetails/Column') T(c)
      where CompanyId = 1 and  ProcessDate = convert(datetime,'01/03/2016',103) and CategoryId in (1) 
            and T.c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') in('FB')
    ) X
  ) B
  ON A.id= B.EmployeeId
) As x
```

> Final GroupBy Condition on Temp Table

```
SELECT B.BENEFICIARY,
       B.BUDHOL,
       B.COMPANY,
       B.FIELDNAME,
       B.OBJECTIVE,
       B.SPARE1,
       B.SPARE2,
       B.PROJECTNO,
       B.TASKNO,
       B.EXPORG,
       B.EXPTYPE,
       SUM(B.value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.BENEFICIARY,
                    A.BUDHOL,
                    A.COMPANY,
                    A.FIELDNAME,
                    A.OBJECTIVE,
                    A.value,
                    A.SPARE2,
                    A.SPARE1,
                    A.PROJECTNO,
                    A.TASKNO,
                    A.EXPORG,
                    A.EXPTYPE
    FROM (
        SELECT t.BENEFICIARY,
               t.BUDHOL,
               t.COMPANY,
               t.FIELDNAME,
               t.OBJECTIVE,
               t.SPARE1,
               t.SPARE2,
               t.PROJECTNO,
               t.TASKNO,
               t.EXPORG,
               t.EXPTYPE,
               t.value value
        FROM #temp T, #temp TT
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN #temp T1 ON A.BENEFICIARY = t1.BENEFICIARY
        AND A.BUDHOL = t1.BUDHOL
        AND A.COMPANY = t1.COMPANY
        AND A.OBJECTIVE = t1.OBJECTIVE
        AND A.SPARE1 = t1.SPARE1
        AND A.SPARE2 = t1.SPARE2
        AND A.PROJECTNO = t1.PROJECTNO
        AND A.TASKNO = t1.TASKNO
        AND A.EXPORG = t1.EXPORG
        AND A.EXPTYPE = t1.EXPTYPE
) B
GROUP BY B.BENEFICIARY,
         B.BUDHOL,
         B.COMPANY,
         B.OBJECTIVE,
         B.FIELDNAME,
         B.SPARE1,
         B.SPARE2,
         B.PROJECTNO,
         B.TASKNO,
         B.EXPORG,
         B.EXPTYPE
```

> Above Query is working fine and as expected.
>   need to know whether above query can be **optimized** so that i can take less time to execute currently it take more than 2 min to execute, also can we combine both queries i.e. i dont want to use **#temp** table

Comment: Please provide your execution plan (sqlplan format)

Comment: Why are doing this cross join? : from #temp T,#temp TT

Comment: @vercelli cross join to take all possible combinations of columns and sum of value

Comment: @Devart Execution plan is very bit not able to copy properly.should i provide you with xml format instead of visual

Comment: But you are only geting t.value, so no sum there. And then you use a DISTINCT so my guess is that you'll get the same result with or without the crossjoin. Is it possible to try the query removing #temp TT and see if the result is the same?

Comment: @Nilesh, you are getting all rows multiplied by all other rows. 10 rows give you 10 times of each row. Not "combinations of column values". All such "combinations" you already have - these are rows in your table. You don't get any _new_ rows by that cross join. And next `left join` makes no sense at all. You just selected from this table - what "surpises" could show there up after this join?

Comment: I'm sorry OP, if one of the developers I work with sent me this for a code review I'd send them right back and tell them to fix it. You're mixing old and new join types, you've got data duplication everywhere. SELECT statements that contain joins are terrible for performance. If you must, make this a function that you call. Any reason that you don't want to use a #temptable?

Comment: it's a CROSS APPLY as opposed to a CROSS JOIN - A CROSS APPLY can give a performance gain in some cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

SELECT A.*, B.*
INTO #temp
FROM (
    SELECT
        e.Id,
        e.code,
        e.Fname,
        c.[BUDHOL],
        c.[COMPANY],
        c.[BENEFICIARY],
        c.[SPARE2],
        c.[SPARE1],
        c.[EXPORG],
        c.[EXPTYPE],
        c.[OBJECTIVE],
        c.[TASKNO],
        c.[PROJECTNO]
    FROM dbo.EmployeeDetail e  
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                  d.CustomeFieldName
                , c.ComboValue
                , d.EmployeeId
            FROM dbo.CustomeFieldDetail d
            LEFT JOIN dbo.comvals c ON c.Id = d.FieldValue
            WHERE d.CustomeFieldName IN (
                    'BENEFICIARY', 'BUDHOL', 'COMPANY',
                    'EXPORG', 'EXPTYPE', 'OBJECTIVE',
                    'PROJECTNO', 'SPARE2', 'SPARE1',
                    'TASKNO', 'COMPANY'
                )
                AND d.CompanyId = 1
        ) src 
        PIVOT (
            MAX(ComboValue)
            FOR CustomeFieldName IN (
                [BENEFICIARY],[BUDHOL],[EXPORG],
                [EXPTYPE],[OBJECTIVE],[PROJECTNO],
                [SPARE2],[SPARE1],
                [TASKNO],[COMPANY]
           )
        ) src2
    ) c ON e.Id = c.EmployeeId
        AND e.DateOfJoining <= '20160330'
    WHERE e.Companyid = 1
) A
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT t.EmployeeId,
           x.[FieldName],
           x.[Value]
    FROM dbo.EmpTransaction t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT t.c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS [FieldName],
               t.c.value('(@Value)[1]', 'FLOAT') AS [Value]
        FROM TransactionFieldDetails.nodes('//PayDetails/Column') t(c)
    ) x
    WHERE [FieldName] = 'FB'
        AND CompanyId = 1
        AND ProcessDate = '20160301'
        AND CategoryId = 1
) B ON A.id = B.EmployeeId

SELECT B.BENEFICIARY,
       B.BUDHOL,
       B.COMPANY,
       B.FIELDNAME,
       B.OBJECTIVE,
       B.SPARE1,
       B.SPARE2,
       B.PROJECTNO,
       B.TASKNO,
       B.EXPORG,
       B.EXPTYPE,
       SUM(B.value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.BENEFICIARY,
                    A.BUDHOL,
                    A.COMPANY,
                    A.FIELDNAME,
                    A.OBJECTIVE,
                    A.value,
                    A.SPARE2,
                    A.SPARE1,
                    A.PROJECTNO,
                    A.TASKNO,
                    A.EXPORG,
                    A.EXPTYPE
    FROM #temp A
    LEFT JOIN #temp T1 ON A.BENEFICIARY = t1.BENEFICIARY
        AND A.BUDHOL = t1.BUDHOL
        AND A.COMPANY = t1.COMPANY
        AND A.OBJECTIVE = t1.OBJECTIVE
        AND A.SPARE1 = t1.SPARE1
        AND A.SPARE2 = t1.SPARE2
        AND A.PROJECTNO = t1.PROJECTNO
        AND A.TASKNO = t1.TASKNO
        AND A.EXPORG = t1.EXPORG
        AND A.EXPTYPE = t1.EXPTYPE
) B
GROUP BY B.BENEFICIARY,
         B.BUDHOL,
         B.COMPANY,
         B.OBJECTIVE,
         B.FIELDNAME,
         B.SPARE1,
         B.SPARE2,
         B.PROJECTNO,
         B.TASKNO,
         B.EXPORG,
         B.EXPTYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

to combine into 1 query

```
WITH temp AS (

select A.*,B.* from 
(select e.Id,e.code,e.Fname,
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.BUDHOL) as [BUDHOL],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.COMPANY) as [COMPANY],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.BENEFICIARY) as [BENEFICIARY],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.SPARE2) as [SPARE2],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.SPARE1) as [SPARE1],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.EXPORG) as [EXPORG],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.EXPTYPE) as [EXPTYPE],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.OBJECTIVE) as [OBJECTIVE],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.TASKNO) as [TASKNO],
(select ComboValue from dbo.comvals where Id = c.PROJECTNO) as [PROJECTNO]
from dbo.EmployeeDetail e  
left join   (select * from   (select CustomeFieldName,FieldValue,CompanyId,EmployeeId   from  dbo.CustomeFieldDetail   where CustomeFieldName in ('BENEFICIARY','BUDHOL','COMPANY', 'EXPORG','EXPTYPE','OBJECTIVE','PROJECTNO','SPARE2','SPARE1','TASKNO','COMPANY') and CompanyId = 1 )as src  pivot (max(FieldValue) for CustomeFieldName in ([BENEFICIARY],[BUDHOL],[EXPORG],[EXPTYPE],[OBJECTIVE],[PROJECTNO],[SPARE2],[SPARE1],[TASKNO],[COMPANY])) as src2) c on e.Id = c.EmployeeId   and e.CompanyId = c.CompanyId and e.DateOfJoining <= convert(datetime,'30/03/2016',103) and e.CompanyId = 1       where e.Companyid=1 --order by e.Code
)A
Full Outer join 
(select
    T.EmployeeId,
    X.[FieldName],
    X.[Value]
from dbo.EmpTransaction T
cross apply (
SELECT         
T.c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') AS [FieldName],
convert(float,T.c.value('(@Value)[1]', 'Varchar(max)')) AS [Value]
FROM TransactionFieldDetails.nodes('//PayDetails/Column') T(c)
where CompanyId = 1 and  ProcessDate = convert(datetime,'01/03/2016',103) and CategoryId in (1) 
and T.c.value('(@Name)[1]', 'Varchar(max)') in('FB')
) X )B
ON A.id= B.EmployeeId

 )
 SELECT B.BENEFICIARY,
       B.BUDHOL,
       B.COMPANY,
       B.FIELDNAME,
       B.OBJECTIVE,
       B.SPARE1,
       B.SPARE2,
       B.PROJECTNO,
       B.TASKNO,
       B.EXPORG,
       B.EXPTYPE,
       SUM(B.value)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.BENEFICIARY,
                    A.BUDHOL,
                    A.COMPANY,
                    A.FIELDNAME,
                    A.OBJECTIVE,
                    A.value,
                    A.SPARE2,
                    A.SPARE1,
                    A.PROJECTNO,
                    A.TASKNO,
                    A.EXPORG,
                    A.EXPTYPE
    FROM (
        SELECT t.BENEFICIARY,
               t.BUDHOL,
               t.COMPANY,
               t.FIELDNAME,
               t.OBJECTIVE,
               t.SPARE1,
               t.SPARE2,
               t.PROJECTNO,
               t.TASKNO,
               t.EXPORG,
               t.EXPTYPE,
               t.value value
        FROM temp T, temp TT
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN #temp T1 ON A.BENEFICIARY = t1.BENEFICIARY
        AND A.BUDHOL = t1.BUDHOL
        AND A.COMPANY = t1.COMPANY
        AND A.OBJECTIVE = t1.OBJECTIVE
        AND A.SPARE1 = t1.SPARE1
        AND A.SPARE2 = t1.SPARE2
        AND A.PROJECTNO = t1.PROJECTNO
        AND A.TASKNO = t1.TASKNO
        AND A.EXPORG = t1.EXPORG
        AND A.EXPTYPE = t1.EXPTYPE
) B
GROUP BY B.BENEFICIARY,
         B.BUDHOL,
         B.COMPANY,
         B.OBJECTIVE,
         B.FIELDNAME,
         B.SPARE1,
         B.SPARE2,
         B.PROJECTNO,
         B.TASKNO,
         B.EXPORG,
         B.EXPTYPE
```